# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$ /estimation vertical lines

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

First of all, I know this very integral has been asked many times on this site (e.g
[$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$ with residue calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643287/int-infty-infty-fraceax1exdx-with-residue-calculus)) and I don't have any problem calculating the residue here and the value of integral.

However I am struggeling in a part of this exercise, that is nowhere elaborated in good detail, namely to show  that the two vertical lines $\to 0$ when $R \to \infty$ (see contour below)
and in all the other threads it is only stated that it is clear that this happens, nowhere could I find a more detailed calculation.

Let $c_1(t)$ be the right vertical line (from $R \to R+2\pi i$)
I have chosen the following parameterization:
$c_1(t)=(1-t)R+(R+2\pi i)t = R +2\pi i t$, $t \in [0,1]$

$c_1'(t) = 2\pi i$
Let $c_3(t)$ be the left vertical line (from $-R+2\pi i \to -R$)

I have chosen the following parameterization:

$c_3(t)=(-R+2 \pi i)(1-t) + (-R)t=-R+2 \pi i(1-t)$, $t \in [0,1]$

$c_3'(t) = -2\pi i$

so for the right vertical line:

|$\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^{a(R+2\pi it)}}{1+e^{R+2\pi it}} 2\pi i dt | \leq 2\pi e^{aR} \int_{0}^{1} |\dfrac{e^{{(2 \pi i)}^{at}}}{1+e^Re^{(2\pi i)^t}}dt| \leq 2\pi e^{aR}  \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{1+e^R} dt = 2\pi \dfrac{e^{aR}}{1+e^{R}}$ (are the steps here justified/correct?)

so for $R \to \infty$ clearly $2\pi \dfrac{e^{aR}}{1+e^{R}} \to 0$ because a < 1 (with l'Hôpital)

for the left vertical line:
$|\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{e^{a(-R)}e^{(2 \pi i)^{a}}e^{(2 \pi i)^{-t}}}{1+e^{-R}e^{2\pi i}e^{({2\pi i})^{-t}}} (-2\pi i) dt | \leq 2\pi\int_{0}^{1} |\dfrac{e^{a(-R)}e^{(2 \pi i)^{a}}e^{(2 \pi i)^{-t}}}{1+e^{-R}e^{2\pi i}e^{({2\pi i})^{-t}}}dt|=2 \pi \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{e^{a(-R)}}{1+e^{-R}}dt$

are the steps until the last equality sign correct?

so I would need to calculate $\lim_{R \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{a(-R)}}{1+e^{-R}}$, but how to evaluate this and show that this will also be zero? I can not use l'Hôpital anymore. what would be the best way here?
[image]

Comment: Hint: change variables viz. $q=e^{-R}$.

Comment: @J.G. thank you for the comment, if $q=e^{-R}$ then I would be having (since $\lim_{R \to \infty} e^{-R} = 0$),  $\lim_{q \to 0} \dfrac{q^{a}}{1+q}$ ? and for $\lim_{q \to 0} \dfrac{q^{a}}{1+q} = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accelerator's answer is very nice, and already corrects your mistakes, so instead of focusing on that, I'll offer an alternative way.

First, note that we must set the restriction of $0<\Re(a)<1$ for your integral to converge.

Next, not dissimilar to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616567/upper-bound-on-zfz-in-a-complex-keyhole-contour-integral/4616607#4616607), we will parameterize the contours and use the [triangle ineq for integrals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5uKbkSy5K4) along with various other variants of the triangle inequalities detailed below.
$$|a+b|\le|a|+|b|\Longleftrightarrow|a-b|\ge||a|-|b||\Longleftrightarrow\frac1{|a-b|}\le\frac1{||a|-|b||}$$

Call the left path $L$, and right path $\mathcal R$. Then, parameterizing them gives
\begin{alignat*}{5}
    \mathcal{R}&:\text{ }z=R+iy,\qquad &\text{d}z&=i\text{ d}y,\qquad &y&\in[0, 2\pi]\\
    L&:\text{ }z=-R+iy,\qquad &\text{d}z&=i\text{ d}y,\qquad &y&\in[2\pi, 0]
\end{alignat*}

where $R$ is some arbitrarily large real number that goes to infinity.

Starting with $\mathcal R$, we have (all in red goes to 1 and thus cancels)
\begin{align}
    \left|\int_{\mathcal{R}}f(z)\text{ d}z\right|&\le\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{\left|e^{aR}\right|{\color{red}{\left|e^{aiy}\right|}}}{\left|e^Re^{iy}+1\right|}\cdot{\color{red}{|i|}}\text{ d}y\\
    &\le\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{e^{|a|R}}{\left|\left|e^R\right|{\color{red}{\left|e^{iy}\right|}}-|-1|\right|}\text{ d}y\\
    &=\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{e^{|a|R}}{e^R-1}\text{ d}y=\frac{2\pi e^{|a|R}}{e^R-1}
\end{align}

Taking the limit gives
$$\lim_{R\to+\infty}\frac{2\pi e^{|a|R}}{e^R-1}=0$$
with our restricted $a$ and thus proves that the integral about $\mathcal{R}$ vanishes.

Using the same arguments for $L$, we have
\begin{align}
    \left|\int_Lf(z)\text{ d}z\right|&\le\int^{0}_{2\pi}\frac{\left|e^{-aR}\right|{\color{red}{\left|e^{aiy}\right|}}}{\left|e^{-R}e^{iy}+1\right|}\cdot{\color{red}{|i|}}\text{ d}y\\
    &\le\int^{0}_{2\pi}\frac{e^{-|a|R}}{\left|\left|e^{-R}\right|{\color{red}{\left|e^{iy}\right|}}-|-1|\right|}\text{ d}y\\
    &=\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{-e^{-|a|R}}{\left|e^{-R}-1\right|}\text{ d}y=\frac{-2\pi e^{-|a|R}}{1-e^{-R}}
\end{align}

Taking the limit will yield
$$\lim_{R\to+\infty}\frac{-2\pi e^{-|a|R}}{1-e^{-R}}=0$$

Hence both integrals along the sides will go to zero since their absolute upper bound is also zero.

Hopefully this makes sense! :)

Comment: perfect, thank you so so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the integral in question is improperly integrable for $a \in (0,1)$. Using the parameterizations you mentioned above,

$$
\eqalign{
0 &\leq \left|\int_{R}^{R+2\pi i}f\left(z\right)dz\right| \cr
&= \left|\int_{0}^{1}f\left(R+2\pi it\right)d\left(R+2\pi it\right)\right| \cr
&\leq 2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left|f\left(R+2\pi it\right)\right|dt \cr
&= 2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left|\frac{e^{aR}e^{2\pi it}}{1+e^{R}e^{2\pi it}}\right|dt \cr
&\leq 2\pi e^{aR}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{e^R-1}dt \text{ (Can you see your mistake?)} \cr
&= \frac{2\pi e^{aR}}{e^{R}-1}. \cr
}
$$
As $R \to \infty$, that last expression goes to $0$. Then you use the Squeeze Theorem to  prove that $\displaystyle \int_{R}^{R+2\pi i}f\left(z\right)dz \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Similarly,

$$
\eqalign{
0 &\leq \left|\int_{-R}^{-R+2\pi i}f\left(z\right)dz\right| \cr
&= \left|\int_{1}^{0}f\left(-R+2\pi i\left(1-t\right)\right)d\left(-R+2\pi i\left(1-t\right)\right)\right| \cr
&= 2\pi\left|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-aR}e^{2\pi i\left(1-t\right)}}{1+e^{-R}e^{2\pi i\left(1-t\right)}}dt\right| \cr
&\leq 2\pi e^{-aR}\int_{0}^{1}\left|\frac{e^{2\pi i\left(1-t\right)}}{1+e^{-R}e^{2\pi i\left(1-t\right)}}\right|dt \cr
&\leq 2\pi e^{-aR}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-e^{-R}}dt \cr
&= \frac{2\pi e^{-aR}}{1-e^{-R}}. \cr
}
$$
(Can you see your mistakes?)
Then
$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\frac{2\pi e^{-aR}}{1-e^{-R}} = \frac{0}{1-0} = 0.$$
Use the Squeeze Theorem to prove $\displaystyle \int_{-R}^{-R+2\pi i}f\left(z\right)dz \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$ and you're done.

Please let me know if there are questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, just one quick question, here $2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left|\frac{e^{aR}e^{2\pi it}}{1+e^{R}e^{2\pi it}}\right|dt \leq 2\pi e^{aR}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-e^{R}}dt$ wouldn't ${1-e^{R}}$ make the denominator negative? wouldn't  that cause any "problems"?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I bounded the denominator wrong. It would cause problems because I would get a negative number for large $R$. It's supposed to be $\left|1+e^{R}e^{2\pi it}\right|\ge\left|\left|1\right|-\left|e^{R}e^{2\pi it}\right|\right|=\left|1-e^{R}\right|=e^{R}-1$. @Inocenciaa

Comment: perfect thank you